# “rouse” vs. “arouse”

Tags: word-choice, differences, american-english

A friend of mine and I were debating the usage of "arouse" and "rouse" in a specific sentence. I do understand that *arouse* and *rouse* are nearly same in meaning; still would like to know more properly.

Which of the following sentences makes more sense?

> - The launch of the app would be very *rousing*.
> - The launch of the app would be very *arousing*.

Comment: "*These are not rules, however, and we could find many exceptions. For example, rousing is often used to describe works of art that induce strong enthusiasm, which is not a physical action. Using rouse this way is probably a smart choice, though, because describing a work of art as arousing might give the impression that the work is pornographic or otherwise erotic*". http://grammarist.com/usage/arouse-rouse/

Comment: Depends ... will this app launch include many attractive and scantily clad people? Then the launch would indeed likely be arousing...

Comment: Similar remarks wrt _wake(n)/awake(n)_, for instance. The _a-_ prefix comes from several sources and has several senses (_high atop the crag, full steam ahead, go afoot, look around, rise/arise,_ etc). And like all [derivational morphology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), it's very irregular and can't be relied on for meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Oxford Dictionary, (I've picked the most appropriate definition), rouse means [Make angry or excited](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rouse)

Arouse is defined as [Evoke or awaken (a feeling, emotion, or response)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arouse)

The subcategory for arouse is almost identical to that of rouse, so it could be used in the same context. However, arouse is almost always used in a sexual context. I think in your case the most "correct" sentence would be the one with rouse.

Edit: aaaidan made a point that arouse is almost always sexual, rather than usually.

Comment: I would go so far as to say it's almost _always_ used in a sexual context. Arouse is, by default, a sexual word.